# map added to form with ability to add polygons and submit via email

Tags: maps

I currently have a section on my website where I ask users to input information on various criteria and the answers get emailed to me (a form with submit button). I would like to add a map to the form in which users can draw shapes such as polygons and circles. Once they submit the form, I would like the map to be emailed along with the other input criteria to me. What is the best code to use?Thank you.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Revised question - how allow a user to add a polygon to a google map?

Answer (score 0):

Never too late ...

You can let the browser open a mail client and send the shapes in the body of the mail.

```
  var text=JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
  window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=' + text);
```

Here is a full [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hDvsD1KN7euUMGy75BPh?p=preview)