# Embed leaflet data collection or geojson.io map to form

Tags: maps, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.draw, data-collection

I'm trying to figure out the most lightweight way to collect data for individual mapped polygons from non-technical users. Here's the end vision: users fill out a web form, draw a shape, and then they can easily email their formatted data to me or my colleagues (I know-- the email idea is probably horrifying readers, but I'm working within a lot of restrictive parameters beyond my control. Email is a known quantity.).

Is there a way to strip down something like geojson.io or even just a leaflet map with leaflet.draw and then pass resulting coordinates into text that can be emailed?

Again, my needs are basic. One shape would be mapped at a time. The fewer visual options and controls the better. My audience is largely very non-technical.

It looks like [this user was trying to ask the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831140/map-added-to-form-with-ability-to-add-polygons-and-submit-via-email), but didn't get far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript), you cannot send your geojson data directly but you can let the browser open a mail client with preset data.

```
  var text=JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
  window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=' + text);
```

Here is a full [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hDvsD1KN7euUMGy75BPh?p=preview)

Comment: This is brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. I think I can eventually build this out into something really functional. Thanks for helping me fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2):

A quick proof of concept, adapting code from [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) example:

```js
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var layer = e.layer,
      popupContent = layer.toGeoJSON ?
        JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()) : "(no data)";

  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
});
```

This converts the drawn item into GeoJSON string, and displays it in a popup bound to the item.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/75/

Comment: Thanks! This is a helpful start. I'm still working on ways to get the geojson out in a way that's not going to overwhelm users with seeing code. But this is a wonderful starting point.